# Why does android studio ask to use remember function with getBackStackEntry?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

After recomposition even if `getBackStackEntry` is not wrapped into `remember` function, it returns one and the same value until a new screen with `userList` route is launched.

**So what's the point of using `remember` function with `getBackStackEntry` ?**

Comment: When you wrap a value assignment or function call with `remember { calculation: () -> T }`, you're instructing Jetpack Compose to execute the calculation in the lambda and only redo it if the value has changed. If you don't wrap your `getBackStackEntry` (which involves a non-trivial calculation) with `remember { }`, then on each composition, the calculation will be performed repeatedly. In contrast, if you do wrap it with `remember { }`, the calculation occurs only once and will be repeated only when the internal value changes. Compose DSL will not call `getBackStackEntry` on each composition.

Comment: @FearNot why not write that up as an answer ? is this a duplicate question ?

Comment: @FearNot  If we launch a new screen with route named as "userList", then `getBackStackEntry` must return a new instance of `NavBackStackEntry`. But in case when we wrap `getBackStackEntry` call into `remember` it will return the previous instance instead of the new one after recomposition. So i still don't get why we have to do it.

Comment: @a_local_nobody That's because I am not that familiar with the Compose navigation to give a more concrete answer.

Comment: @VanechikSpace You should not wrap it in a key-less`remember { }`, you should wrap it in a `remember(key) { }` which will redo the calculation whenever the key changes. The key in this case has to be a `NavBackStackEntry` key as per the java docs. I am not sure what that is exactly though